# JSF EL set string property to null

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, el

I have a string field `borderColor` in a bean that I wan't to set to `null` using EL but it is always being coerced to an empty string.

```
<p:inputText value="#{axis.borderColor}" rendered="#{axis.borderColor != null}">
    <p:ajax update=":form:plot"/>
</p:inputText>

<p:commandButton value="#{msg.initialize}" action="#{axis.setBorderColor( 'cccccc' )}" rendered="#{axis.borderColor == null}" update=":form:mainTabs:axesSettings :form:plot"/>
<p:commandButton value="#{msg.reset}" rendered="#{axis.borderColor != null}" update=":form:mainTabs:axesSettings :form:plot">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{axis.borderColor}" value="#{null}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

- If `borderColor` is null I display an "Initialize" button.
- If `borderColor` is not null I display a text field where the user can type in a CSS color and a "Reset" button. When the reset button is pressed I want to set the borderColor back to null (I'm actually using the PrimeFaces p:colorPicker rather than a text field but the problem is the same).

I've read all about `javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL` and I thought adding that context parameter would fix the problem but it didn't have any effect. It seems the null value being supplied by the `setPropertyActionListener` is being converted to an empty string for some reason.

I'm using GlassFish 4.0 and PrimeFaces 4.0-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Have you tried without `rendered="#{axis.borderColor != null}"` ? You probably need to wrap your button inside an `h:panelGroup rendered="#{axis.borderColor != null}"` for example.

Comment: Yes, I've tried it with out the `rendered="..."` and I've placed the button and text field in a h:panelGroup - none of those worked. I've put logging on the setBorderColor method so I know for sure an empty string is being passed in. I suspect the null in the action listener is being passed through a string converter or something like that.

Comment: I've already done what you are trying in the past, without problem, without custom config. The only difference I see is GlassFish, I almost always use Tomcat... worth a try?

Comment: Unfortunately I rely on features that only a full Java EE server provides. I might try a demo app though to see if the behaviour is different. I should probably say that I'm using exactly this patten to  set Boolean, Double, Integer, etc to null, it only fails with String properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need pass null value to a property. You can use eq to validate an empty or null string

```
<p:inputText value="#{axis.borderColor}" rendered="#{not empty axis.borderColor}">
    <p:ajax update=":form:plot"/>
</p:inputText>
```

Comment: I'm going to vote this up as it has solved my problem but not answered the underlying question. The borderColor is still being set to an empty string rather than null but using `empty` allows me to hide the relevant components. Fortunately for me in this case the application doesn't really care whether the string is null or empty but I can see I'll want to set things to null in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do the following setting in your `web.xml` to force setting `null`, which doesn't happen by default in JSF2.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that already as mentioned in the second to last paragraph.